# Blink a message at every 10 seconds after that stop for 10 seconds and blink again

Tags: javascript, html

My Html Code

```
<a id="blink">123qwe</a>
```

My java-script code

```
var stopBlinking = false;
setTimeout(function() 
{
   stopBlinking = true;
}, 10000);


function blink(selector) {
    $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).fadeIn('slow', function() {
            if (!stopBlinking)
            {
                blink(this);
            }
            else
            {
               setInterval(function() 
                            {
                                stopBlinking = true;
                            }, 10000);
             }
        });
    });
}
blink("#blink");
```

This code is not blink after 10 seconds. what's the problem in this code?

please help me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the effect you're after. Could you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do? Regardless, it sounds to me like you should be doing it with CSS animations/transitions, instead of JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: @Madara Uchihai want to blink a message for 10 seconds after that that message should be stop to blink for next 10 seconds. and after that again start blinking. its like cycle of blinking a message. 10sec start - > 10sec stop -> 10sec start wise versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var interval = 10000;
var stopBlinking = false;

function blink(selector) {
    if(stopBlinking)
        return false;
 
    $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).fadeIn('slow', function() {
            blink(this);
        });
    });
}

blink("#blink");

setInterval(function(){ 
    stopBlinking = !stopBlinking; 
    blink("#blink");
}, interval);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="blink">123qwe</a>
```

Comment: I agree - this is a neater way of doing it than my answer

Answer (score 1):

```js
var stopBlinking = false;
setTimeout(function() {
  stopBlinking = true;
}, 10000);


function blink(selector) {
  $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).fadeIn('slow', function() {
      if (!stopBlinking) {
        blink(this);
      } else {
        stopBlinking = false;
        setTimeout(function() {
          blink(selector)
          setTimeout(function() {
            stopBlinking = true;
          }, 10000);
        }, 10000);
      }
    });
  });
}

blink("#blink");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="blink">Blinking Message</a>
```

Comment: what is the best way to do like this using css